# "No columns to parse from file" error when trying to transform string into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, stringio

I have a string object ("textData") which contains CSV data.

I'm able to save it as CSV by:

```
    with open(fileName, "w") as text_file:
        print(textData, file=text_file)
```

but I would like to work with the data in pandas before saving the csv. So I'm trying to get the data into a pandas df.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textData), sep=",")
```

I get this error: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

This is a the textData string:

```
R$M21,2021-01-26,1.3265,1.3265,1.3265,1.3265,0,0
R$M21,2021-01-27,1.3263,1.3263,1.3263,1.3263,0,0
R$M21,2021-01-28,1.3319,1.3319,1.3319,1.3319,0,0
R$M21,2021-01-29,1.3287,1.3287,1.3287,1.3287,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-01,1.3315,1.3315,1.3315,1.3315,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-02,1.3328,1.3328,1.3328,1.3328,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-03,1.3331,1.3331,1.3331,1.3331,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-04,1.3361,1.3361,1.3361,1.3361,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-05,1.3383,1.3383,1.3383,1.3383,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-08,1.3354,1.3354,1.3354,1.3354,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-09,1.3279,1.3279,1.3279,1.3279,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-10,1.3259,1.3259,1.3259,1.3259,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-11,1.3253,1.3253,1.3253,1.3253,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-12,1.3272,1.3272,1.3272,1.3272,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-15,1.3224,1.3224,1.3224,1.3224,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-16,1.3232,1.3232,1.3232,1.3232,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-17,1.329,1.329,1.329,1.329,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-18,1.3275,1.3275,1.3275,1.3275,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-19,1.3246,1.3246,1.3246,1.3246,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-22,1.3235,1.3235,1.3235,1.3235,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-23,1.3216,1.3216,1.3216,1.3216,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-24,1.321,1.321,1.321,1.321,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-25,1.3181,1.3181,1.3181,1.3181,0,0
R$M21,2021-02-26,1.3313,1.3313,1.3313,1.3313,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-01,1.3323,1.3323,1.3323,1.3323,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-02,1.3315,1.3315,1.3315,1.3315,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-03,1.3309,1.3309,1.3309,1.3309,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-04,1.3328,1.3328,1.3328,1.3328,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-05,1.3417,1.3417,1.3417,1.3417,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-08,1.3479,1.3479,1.3479,1.3479,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-09,1.345,1.345,1.345,1.345,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-10,1.3476,1.3476,1.3476,1.3476,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-11,1.3403,1.3403,1.3403,1.3403,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-12,1.3463,1.3463,1.3463,1.3463,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-15,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,35,35
R$M21,2021-03-16,1.3455,1.3456,1.3452,1.3454,85,20
R$M21,2021-03-17,1.3457,1.3479,1.3451,1.3479,0,20
R$M21,2021-03-18,1.3432,1.3432,1.3432,1.3432,0,20
R$M21,2021-03-19,1.3425,1.3425,1.3425,1.3425,20,0
R$M21,2021-03-22,1.3434,1.3434,1.3405,1.3405,20,0
R$M21,2021-03-23,1.3433,1.3433,1.3433,1.3433,0,0
R$M21,2021-03-24,1.3461,1.3461,1.3461,1.3461,6,6
R$M21,2021-03-25,1.3476,1.3476,1.3472,1.3472,0,6
R$M21,2021-03-26,1.3477,1.3477,1.3477,1.3477,0,6
R$M21,2021-03-29,1.3467,1.3467,1.3467,1.3467,0,6
R$M21,2021-03-30,1.3483,1.3483,1.3483,1.3483,0,6
R$M21,2021-03-31,1.3448,1.3448,1.3448,1.3448,0,6
R$M21,2021-04-01,1.3461,1.3461,1.3461,1.3461,0,6
R$M21,2021-04-02,1.3442,1.3442,1.3442,1.3442,0,6
R$M21,2021-04-05,1.3446,1.3446,1.3446,1.3446,0,6
R$M21,2021-04-06,1.3418,1.3418,1.3418,1.3418,10,11
R$M21,2021-04-07,1.339,1.3398,1.3389,1.3389,0,11
R$M21,2021-04-08,1.3406,1.3406,1.3406,1.3406,0,11
R$M21,2021-04-09,1.3411,1.3411,1.3411,1.3411,23,28
R$M21,2021-04-12,1.3427,1.3427,1.3406,1.3406,3,31
R$M21,2021-04-13,1.3425,1.3431,1.3425,1.3431,20,51
R$M21,2021-04-14,1.3374,1.3378,1.3374,1.3375,0,51
R$M21,2021-04-15,1.335,1.335,1.335,1.335,217,222
R$M21,2021-04-16,1.3358,1.3358,1.3337,1.3337,416,407
R$M21,2021-04-19,1.3344,1.3346,1.331,1.331,370,428
R$M21,2021-04-20,1.3305,1.3316,1.3265,1.3283,5,431
R$M21,2021-04-21,1.3291,1.3302,1.3291,1.3302,100,422
R$M21,2021-04-22,1.3304,1.3304,1.3279,1.3279,10,427
R$M21,2021-04-23,1.3277,1.3277,1.3274,1.3274,16,437
R$M21,2021-04-26,1.3273,1.3273,1.3256,1.326,204,438
R$M21,2021-04-27,1.3259,1.3267,1.3255,1.3257,79,429
R$M21,2021-04-28,1.3274,1.3278,1.3262,1.3262,22,441
R$M21,2021-04-29,1.326,1.3265,1.3245,1.3255,16,457
R$M21,2021-04-30,1.3266,1.3277,1.3266,1.3277,60,457
R$M21,2021-05-03,1.328,1.3341,1.328,1.3318,8,458
R$M21,2021-05-04,1.3298,1.3366,1.3298,1.3366,110,466
R$M21,2021-05-05,1.3376,1.3387,1.3351,1.3358,0,466
R$M21,2021-05-06,1.3349,1.3349,1.3349,1.3349,1,467
R$M21,2021-05-07,1.332,1.332,1.3316,1.3316,25,466
R$M21,2021-05-10,1.3263,1.3263,1.3247,1.3247,187,480
R$M21,2021-05-11,1.3244,1.3276,1.3244,1.3251,6,486
R$M21,2021-05-12,1.329,1.329,1.3287,1.3287,119,586
R$M21,2021-05-13,1.3312,1.3366,1.3294,1.3343,270,738
R$M21,2021-05-14,1.3346,1.3371,1.3338,1.3338,392,841
R$M21,2021-05-17,1.3332,1.3361,1.3319,1.3356,99,835
R$M21,2021-05-18,1.3358,1.3358,1.3295,1.33,93,785
R$M21,2021-05-19,1.3295,1.333,1.3287,1.3328,25,784
R$M21,2021-05-20,1.335,1.3354,1.3326,1.3329,26,773
R$M21,2021-05-21,1.3309,1.3309,1.3301,1.3301,25,777
R$M21,2021-05-24,1.3298,1.3318,1.3298,1.3301,39,767
R$M21,2021-05-25,1.3293,1.3293,1.3253,1.3254,28,782
R$M21,2021-05-26,1.3249,1.3249,1.323,1.3235,48,770
R$M21,2021-05-27,1.3245,1.3247,1.3229,1.3229,51,805
R$M21,2021-05-28,1.3238,1.3247,1.323,1.3244,76,826
R$M21,2021-05-31,1.3237,1.3237,1.3223,1.3226,16,826
R$M21,2021-06-01,1.3194,1.3227,1.3194,1.3227,34,808
R$M21,2021-06-02,1.323,1.3248,1.322,1.3248,50,785
R$M21,2021-06-03,1.3235,1.3245,1.3228,1.3244,137,720
R$M21,2021-06-04,1.3276,1.3285,1.3274,1.3285,219,564
R$M21,2021-06-07,1.3251,1.3252,1.3232,1.3232,42,544
R$M21,2021-06-08,1.3236,1.3238,1.3226,1.3237,290,343
R$M21,2021-06-09,1.3232,1.3243,1.3231,1.3233,48,343
R$M21,2021-06-10,1.3239,1.3253,1.3238,1.3244,406,292
R$M21,2021-06-11,1.3249,1.3261,1.3217,1.324,107,0
R$M21,2021-06-14,1.3252,1.3271,1.3252,1.3261,107,0
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: IF it is a csv file can't you just pd.read_csv(filename.csv) it?

Comment: It is not a csv file, but an object resulting from web scraping. I know I could save the textData object as a CSV file and then importing the CSV file into Pandas, but I would prefer to avoid saving the CSV file

Comment: How did you create that?  If I cut and paste THAT EXACT STRING into my code, it work just fine.  Therefore, that isn't your exact string.  Do you have newline characters separating the lines?  Or did you just concatenate a whole bunch of strings without using newlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the parts you aren't showing us, because your code works fine.  I'm guessing you don't have newlines separating the lines.

```
C:\tmp>type x.py

textData="""\
R$M21,2021-06-08,1.3236,1.3238,1.3226,1.3237,290,343
R$M21,2021-06-09,1.3232,1.3243,1.3231,1.3233,48,343
R$M21,2021-06-10,1.3239,1.3253,1.3238,1.3244,406,292
R$M21,2021-06-11,1.3249,1.3261,1.3217,1.324,107,0
R$M21,2021-06-14,1.3252,1.3271,1.3252,1.3261,107,0"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textData), sep=",")
print(df)

C:\tmp>python x.py
   R$M21  2021-06-08  1.3236  1.3238  1.3226  1.3237  290  343
0  R$M21  2021-06-09  1.3232  1.3243  1.3231  1.3233   48  343
1  R$M21  2021-06-10  1.3239  1.3253  1.3238  1.3244  406  292
2  R$M21  2021-06-11  1.3249  1.3261  1.3217  1.3240  107    0
3  R$M21  2021-06-14  1.3252  1.3271  1.3252  1.3261  107    0

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: I edited my question and posted the whole content of textData. Is there a way to make it readable  by pandas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to **add newline** after each line, best through `os.linesep`.

Then **set** the `StringIO` **buffer** "head position" **to start**, aka 0, before passing it to pandas:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write('hello,23,2022,bye' + os.linesep)
buffer.write('world,43,2025,then' + os.linesep)
buffer.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=',', header=None)

print(df)
```

This will yield:

```
       0   1     2     3
0  hello  23  2022   bye
1  world  43  2025  then
```

[Python-3.9]